# Number of ways to buy ice cream

Tags: combinatorics

There are $10$ types of ice creams available. We want to buy $3$ for each of $20$ students. In how many ways can this be done?

Since there is no restriction on the number of times an ice cream can be taken, one can choose all three different ice creams, or even all same ice creams. This is where my confusion begins.

There are $10^3$ ways to choose $3$ ice creams with repetition, but in this way, I'll be over counting in the sense that $ABC, CAB, BCA$ and so on correspond to the same set of ice creams, which have been counted separately.

If I consider the cases where a student takes all same ice creams, two same and one different ice cream, all different ice creams separately, I would also have to consider the number of students taking them.

Please give me some hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Choose which icecream**s** (*plural*) student A has.  Then choose for student B, and so on...  If you don't know how to count that yet, the search term is "stars and bars"

Comment: I didn't think this problem using stars and bars. So, I think it can be done as follows: Consider 10 dots and 3 bars. Any arrangement of these, student A chooses ice cream number corresponding to the dot to the immediate left of each bar. So, bars won't be placed before first dot. Number of such arrangements is equal to arrangement of 9 dots and 3 bars (one dot is added at the beginning after arrangement). So, ways in which student A can choose ice creams is $C(9,3)$. Therefore, final answer would be ${C(9,3)}^{20}$. Is this correct? @JMoravitz

Comment: There are $3$ dots and $9$ bars.  Each bar is used to signify where one flavor starts and another flavor ends.  The dots represent the scoops of icecream themselves.  So, with flavors Apple, Banana, Chocolate, Dark chocolate, ... an arrangement of $\star \mid \star \mid \star\mid \mid \mid \mid$... corresponds to the person getting one scoop of apple, one scoop of banana and one scoop of chocolate while $\mid \star\mid \star\star\mid\mid\mid$... corresponds to getting one scoop banana and two scoops chocolate, etc...  Note, we use one fewer bar than the number of flavors

Comment: As alluded to in my previous comment, there are $\binom{12}{3}=\binom{12}{9}=\binom{3+10-1}{10-1}=\dots$ number of ways for an individual to have chosen their flavors.  Applying rule of product over all persons, this gives $\binom{12}{3}^{20}$ total ways in which the group of people can receive their ice cream (*assuming persons are distinct, repetition of flavors and flavor combinations are allowed, and order of flavors within each person's selection is irrelevant*)

Comment: We can probably consider like this also for each student. C(10, 3) for all distinct, 2 X C(10, 2) for one repeat flavor (since any one out of 2 selected can be repeated) and C(10, 1) for one flavor only. Summation of this gives C(12, 3).